# Can you see notification messages again once you tapped on the messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

If you use messaging services like WeChat, you get messages notification when you receive it. Then if you tap on them, it would get you to the app where the received message is on the top screen page.

However, I would like to see messages on the notification center again that I already tapped on. This is because sometimes my friends in WeChat retract or delete the messages, and once I land on the app, I can't see what they write in their messages.

But as long as the messages are still in the notification center, I can read it. Is it possible to see these messages again in iPhone (iOS 10)?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Crypto.com had a notification, "Be the first 50 people to buy $50 of ____ or ____ or ____ and win $50" (something like that), and that I tap on it, and it brought me to their app without any details.  So now I am completely lost... I may be able to contact them and find out in 30 minutes or 1 hour, but I don't think I will be the first 50... bravo to this new era of programmers. "BOOM BAM!" it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a notification is removed from Notification Center, it is no longer available. Notifications are not stored historically elsewhere.